# Проблема с визуальными артефактами на дороге игры после загрузки на Яндекс Игры в Unity WebGL

Tags: c#, unity3d, webgl, яндекс-игры

Я разрабатываю игру в Unity, в которой есть бесконечная дорога, и текстура дороги сдвигается для имитации движения. Все работало отлично, пока я не загрузил игру на платформу Яндекс Игры. После этого на дороге начали появляться визуальные артефакты, которые становились все более размытыми с увеличением дистанции.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я подозреваю, что проблема связана с настройками рендера, так как в Unity все работает корректно. Вот участок кода, который отвечает за движение текстуры дороги:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class moveway : MonoBehaviour
{
   private float _offset;

   private void Update()
   {
       _offset -= 0.05f;
       GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureOffset = new Vector2(0, _offset);
   }
}
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). в частности: заголовок «проблема с тем-то» — не очень хороший заголовок.

Comment: Скриншот с визуальными артефактами прикладывайте пожалуйста )

Comment: вот ссылка на скриншот https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CECG8uOn9OQaJT1SYuYEnf8w_mZJ8yVX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причиной размытия является фильтрация текстур. Это не артефакты, без нее, детали в дали превращаются в жуткое месиво пикселей, невыносимо ребящее в движении что является реальными артефактами, как на картинке сверху-справо `Point Filtering`.

Уровень фильтрации зависит от расстояния и качества. В графических настройках `Unity` есть несколько наборов настроек. В зависимости от пайплайна, классического или `URP`, они отличаются. Для `WebGL` скорее всего используется набор минимальных настроек, редактор использует более высокий, но это можно изменить, что бы стразу наблюдать таргетовые настройки.

Так-же я подозриваю, что у тебя сцена в гигантических масштабах, где `scale` желтого шарика не `1x1x1`, а что-то типа `1000x1000x1000`.